# JetBrains PHPStorm: Adding Remote PHP Interpreter unable to connect to PHP executable

Tags: php, ssh, phpstorm, xdebug, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to add a remote PHP interpreter to PHPStorm to allow xdebug debugging.  When adding an interpreter I'm able to set up the SSH creds properly and connect to the server.  However, when I set my PHP executable PHPStorm is not then able to access that executable for some reason, returning `PHP Version: Not installed`.

Here's what my screen looks like:
[image: This is what my executable is set to]

And here you can see that when I navigate to the correct directory the php binary is actually there.

[image: First dir listing]
[image: Second dir listing]

I have tried choosing other php binaries on this server and none of them work.

Any help?

Edit:
I've included a picture of what the permissions look like for the php dir in question:
[image]

Comment: is this a permissions issue? does your ssh user have access to the `php` binary?

Comment: Good question, I've confirmed that it does have access to the ```php``` binary.

Comment: I suggest checking `idea.log` for possible hints (`Help | Show log in...`). Most likely permission issue.

Comment: I may also suggest trying Remote Terminal, login using those details and try to execute that php executable there.

Comment: In addition to the successful ssh connection and uploading of the helpers I get this:

2015-10-07 10:07:05,114 [208808105]   INFO - esdk.transport.JschExecProcess - Executing ssh command: env "JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN"="1" /opt/alt/php53/usr/bin/php /home/%%USERNAME/.phpstorm_helpers/phpinfo.php for %%USERNAME@%%HOSTNAME:%%PORTNAME 

The user has the ability to run this executable.  I can do it through normal SSH from an OS X terminal or through PHPStorm's terminal.  Can you explain further how it could still be a permissions issue?